# Filter an Rdd[String] based on data indicator if it is present otherwise filter based on header and trailer indicator present of file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a csv file, where each line may or may not begin with data indicator.I need to check if the data indicator is present then I've to read the records based on it, otherwise I've to read records based on the header and trailer indicator. How I can achieve this

Currently I have this code:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)

val rdd1 = rdd.filter(x=>x.startsWith(dataIndicator.get))
```

But this code will fail when the dataIndicator field is missing in the input file and this dataIndicator field is defined as an `Option[String]` in case class.

Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
val rdd1 = dataIndicator match {
  case Some(di) => rdd.filter(x => x.startsWith(di))
  case None => rdd.filter(x => x.startsWith(headerAndTrailerIndicator))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Can you pls explain how this di will match with dataIndicator value. And if dataIndicator is absent in the file, then my requirement is to check for trailer and header indicator and if both are present then read the actual data, not the data begins with header and trailer

Comment: I managed to achieve the 2nd part of my requirement. Thanks for the input for handling optional field..